# YouTube Analytics API 400 Bad Request

Tags: youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I was trying to fetch YouTube analytics data and to get the access token for the same. I have followed the procedure given https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/authentication. We got the code but when i have tried to use POST request to get access token,i got the 400 bad request.Please help.

My Post request:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1  //Post Rquest
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/M7LjucbJDYrZCMiqymuKCmbGxvJk...&
client_id=8465043....apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=8gn6f7K...&
redirect_uri=https://qsmi.qualcomm.com/oauth2callback&
grant_type=authorization_code
response_type=4/M7LjucbJDYrZCMiqymuKCmbGxvJk...
```

One more thing do we have to ask for whitelisting of app or i am missing anything. Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** need whitelisting for using Analytics API.

You don't need "response_type" in your POST request as described under #4 in
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/authentication#OAuth2_Flows

Please try omitting that.

But before that, you need do the step 1 first to grant access offline.

Example:

```
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback&
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly&
response_type=code&
access_type=offline`
```

Comment: I have omitted the response_type but still getting the same error.

Comment: feel free to share all your request and response and I'll look into it. ulukaya@google